# Shnayim Umeya Va-elef - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows eleven hundred two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: What did you drink already?

Comment: Just getting into the spirit (no pun intended).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Over the course of some leap years, there are precisely 1102 *olim*/*aliyos* (to the Torah).

- In a בש״ז year (i.e., one that starts on Monday and in which *Cheshvan* has thirty days), people in Israel in an area that keeps *Purim* on the fourteenth of *Adar* who have five *olim* on the night of *Sh'mini Atzeres* (=*Simchas Tora*), eight on its day, and none on the afternoons of *b'hab* have a total of 1102 *olim*.
- In a בח״ה year (i.e., one that starts on a Monday and in which *Kislev* has twenty-nine days), people outside of Israel in an area that keeps *Purim* on the fourteenth of *Adar* who have three *olim* on the night of *Simchas Tora*, eight on its day, and three on each afternoon of *b'hab* have a total of 1102 *olim*.
- In a גכ״ז year (i.e., one that starts on a Tuesday and in which *Cheshvan* and *Kislev*, combined, have fifty-nine days), I can't think of a combination of customs that would yield 1102 *olim*.

I've only checked those three of the seven configurations of leap years (and have no plans to check the rest). I doubt that any non-leap year would have 1102 *olim*, but haven't checked.

Comment: I don't usually change my mind on the checkmark for these, but I also don't usually go out of order with the numbers. Nice work!

Answer (score 5):

> Before the outbreak of World War II, there were 1,102 Jewish women to every 1,000 Jewish men in the Soviet Union....

—[Benjamin Pinkus, *The Soviet Government and the Jews 1948–1967*, page 27](http://books.google.com/books?id=V7g8AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA27&dq=1102)

Comment: Sounds like a Shidduch crisis to me

Answer (score 4):

2 days of Purim - Purim and Shushan Purim

100 Brachos we make each day

1000 times every mother tells her children "Enough nosh already"!