# Arba'a Veshiv'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred seventy-four?

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 274.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred seventy-three entries in this ongoing series.

Comment: Why the sudden change in format?

Comment: @Dave 1. I have to make some change each time or the SE engine rejects it preemptively as a dupe. 2. It's nice to keep things fresh. 3. To provide a little more explanation for people who may not have already figured it out, especially given that I've slowed down on the frequency of these a great deal.

Comment: [The previous 274](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6430)?

Comment: @msh210, yeah, for some values of "previous." Either choice could result in confusion, and I chose the one that looks right before you start digging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Parshas Noach - Breishis 9:24 - **וייקץ נח  = 274**

Answer (score 1):

[In 1686, when the Holy Roman Empire took Buda from the Turks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Buda_%281686%29#Second_siege.2C_1686), the captors killed the city's Jews, but one Sender Tausk of Prague ransomed 274 of them to safety, according to a contemporary poem [cited by Hilde Pach](http://books.google.com/books?id=syFFpCwBlacC&pg=PA215&dq=sender).